# How can I allow a 3rd party to PUT objects into S3 via API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I need to be able to allow a 3rd party to PUT objects into one of our S3 buckets. I have the bucket and API Gateway set up so that I can use Postman to PUT objects. I've been doing it through the console before Terraforming it. Been at it for 3 days now, brain fried, I need to ask for help.

Here are key parts of the API Gateway:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And now the IAM stuff - this could be the problem:

[image]

I made an assumption that the Trust relationship should be used.

[image]

The Role itself is just this:

[image]

In Postman:

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered a design where the client requests an upload from your API, your API responds to the client with a temporary, pre-signed URL for POST/PUT, and then the client uploads directly to S3 using that pre-signed URL?

Comment: I haven't - is that a better solution? I'd be happy for the client to have long-term access.

Comment: If you're planning to write an API anyway, simply have the API authenticate the client and then let the client initiate an upload to S3 by asking your API for a pre-signed URL. That way, you control the key of the object that the client creates so you can force all of joe's uploads to be under joe/, for example. And you don't have to proxy the uploads to S3 - trust me, S3 scales better than your app ;-) Not sure what you mean by "I'd be happy for the client to have long-term access" - pre-signed URLs are time-limited but the client can request them from your API whenever it needs to upload.